# installanywhere can not run signed jar

Tags: java, installanywhere

I have an existing install anywhere script which runs fine with a unsigned jar. I can create the exe, exe install properly and run fine. Recently I signed my jar, the jar individually run fine but when I create an exe out of it using installanywhere the exe installs fine but does not run.

Any ideas ?
Thanks !

Comment: What version of installanywhere do you use?? There seem to be some problems with older versions not willing to run signed jar files

Comment: What does "does not run" mean? I guess that you get exception, right?

Comment: I am using 2012 standard

Comment: Once i run the exe it does not do anything.. Is there anywhere it creates a log. I checked windows system event but do not see anything.

Comment: installanywhere supports signed jar files from version 2011 SP3. But as far as I understand, only jar files, that are dependencies to the main code. As far as I understand the documentation, you can sign your custom code jar files with installanywhere, no need to do it beforehand.

Comment: In my case the main jar file (i.e. my application) is signed. I also checked custom code but seems like its not of my use. Let me know if you think otherwise